# Spotify Apps API: Spotify crashes all the time

Tags: spotify

I'm working on a Spotify App, but the Spotify application keeps crashing on me. I have been trying to debug my own Javascript code, to see where it goes wrong, but it seems a bit random. It almost always happens when my app loses focus (i.e. switch to another app). Is there a compatibility issue with jQuery perhaps?

Unfortunately I can't find any crash-logs or anything, for Spotify. Are there any?

I hope someone can help me along here, because this problem makes developing cool Spotify Apps as good as impossible.

Edit: To clarify, I'm using Spotify 0.8.8.450.gd9413514, on Windows 8 64-bit, but I've also experienced the same on Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 7, you can create a crash log by accessing the Task Manager, right clicking the Spotify process and selecting "Create dump file". If you're on Mac OS X, you can get a crash dump by opening the Activity Monitor, selecting the Spotify process and clicking 'Sample Process'.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems, It seems related to ads banner on the top. Run the ad video and pause it, that solved the problem for me.